# Yii Framework: Setting attribute to NULL

Tags: sql

I have this code and i need to set it to `NULL`. What is the correct way?

```
$criteria->condition='tblvisit_batch_id=NULL';
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for -- can you refine your question?

Answer (score 3):

You should use correct SQL statement :

```
$criteria->condition='tblvisit_batch_id IS NULL';
```